# CSS theming of GtkCalendar marked days

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to modify existing theme `.css` files for a Linux Desktop (Ubuntu Unity in my case), so that they suit my needs. Looking at already existing themes I was able to reverse engineer most of it, but for some widgets I was not able to theme them properly. On of it are the marked days in a GtkCalendar. 
What do I need to modify in the `.css` files so that I can modify the font-color of the marked days (the ones bold in the Calendar, i.e. Something is happening at that day; red rectangle). It is not the `color` property because `color:` only changes the color of the non-marked days (as it can be seen in the screenshot,28th December)

For reference: This is the file I'm trying to modify. It's written in SASS but that doesn't matter https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix/blob/master/gtk-3.0/scss/widgets/_calendar.scss

[image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML? I need to see the class being used on the marked days and most of all the architecture of the calendar itself. SCSS works great if the specificity is defined correctly

Comment: I pasted the GtkCalendar part, I hope that's what you wanted: http://pastebin.com/pPgquwiW

Comment: I meant the markup of the calendar after runtime. The source. I'm assuming this puts out a table, and the marked days have a class 'current day' or 'today', etc.

Comment: You mean this? https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCalendar.html. Sorry if I don't get what you mean...

Comment: The source should be there: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-calendar/

Comment: I suggest you add the code to your question specially your css and html code if you are looking for a css solution. The way S.O. works is you do the footwork, post the relevant code here and we test, debug, and fix it for you. Simply sending us to a repository is not right. Read through this site's rules and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @wa4557 What we need to help you solve this is your calendar displayed on a publicly viewable URL, with one of the days marked. (Just guessing by the GtkCalendar docs, that's related to a gtk_calendar_mark_day function?) Once the rendered HTML is in my inspector I can help out.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Looks like a miscommunication here; there isn't any HTML markup. GTK is a toolkit for native desktop apps, that also happens to use CSS for theming, but not via rendering into HTML.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a placeholder to test the functionality.

```
gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss           |   10 ++++++++--
 gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css |    9 ++++++++-
 gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css      |    9 ++++++++-
 3 files changed, 24 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
---
diff --git a/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss b/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss
index 6f70d4f..bcd5f80 100644
--- a/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss
+++ b/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss
@@ -2761,13 +2761,19 @@ GtkCalendar {
   text-align: center; /* haha, dream on */
 }
 .day.dim-label{ color: $insensitive_fg_color; }
-.day:selected {
+.day.day:selected {
   color: $selected_fg_color;
   background-color: $selected_bg_color;
   padding: 0.4em;
   border-radius: 3px;
 }
-
+.day.holiday,
+.day.weekend {
+  background-color: transparentize(red, 0.9);
+}
+.day.marked {
+  font-weight: bold;
+}

 /***********
  * Dialogs *
diff --git a/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css b/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css
index c46cb5a..c593cc2 100644
--- a/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css
+++ b/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css
@@ -3678,12 +3678,19 @@ GtkCalendar {
 .header-bar .day.subtitle {
   color: #939695; }

-.day:selected {
+.day.day:selected {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #215d9c;
   padding: 0.4em;
   border-radius: 3px; }

+.day.holiday,
+.day.weekend {
+  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1); }
+
+.day.marked {
+  font-weight: bold; }
+
 /***********
  * Dialogs *
  ***********/
diff --git a/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css b/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css
index 050dece..aca3a5b 100644
--- a/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css
+++ b/gtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css
@@ -3848,12 +3848,19 @@ GtkCalendar {
 .header-bar .day.subtitle {
   color: #8d9091; }

-.day:selected {
+.day.day:selected {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #4a90d9;
   padding: 0.4em;
   border-radius: 3px; }

+.day.holiday,
+.day.weekend {
+  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1); }
+
+.day.marked {
+  font-weight: bold; }
+
 /***********
  * Dialogs *
  ***********/
```